# DuplicateWidgetID: There are multiple widgets with the same key='input'. on streamlit chat app

Tags: python, streamlit

I have the following code,

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    st.title('Scenario 2: Question Aswering on documents with langchain, pinecone and openai')
    st.markdown(
        """
        This scenario shows the Stuff Chain.

        Stuffing is the simplest method, whereby you simply stuff all the related data into the prompt as context to pass to the language model. This is implemented in LangChain as the StuffDocumentsChain.
        
        - Pros: Only makes a single call to the LLM. When generating text, the LLM has access to all the data at once.
        - Cons: Most LLMs have a context length, and for large documents (or many documents) this will not work as it will result in a prompt larger than the context length.
        
        The main downside of this method is that it only works on smaller pieces of data. Once you are working with many pieces of data, this approach is no longer feasible. The next two approaches are designed to help deal with that.
        """
    )

    pinecone.init(
        api_key=PINECONE_API_KEY,  # find at app.pinecone.io
        environment=PINECONE_ENV  # next to api key in console
    )
        
    if 'generated' not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state['generated'] = []

    if 'past' not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state['past'] = []

    def get_text():
        input_text = st.text_input("You: ","", key="input")
        return input_text 
    
    def query(payload, chain):   
        response = chain.run(input_documents=docs, question=get_text())
        thisdict = {
            "generated_text": response
        }
        return thisdict

    index_name = "default"
    index = pinecone.Index(index_name)
    embed = OpenAIEmbeddings(deployment=OPENAI_EMBEDDING_DEPLOYMENT_NAME, model=OPENAI_EMBEDDING_MODEL_NAME, chunk_size=1)
    docsearch = Pinecone.from_existing_index(index_name, embed)
    docs = docsearch.similarity_search(get_text())    
    text_field = "text"
    vectorstore = Pinecone(index, embed.embed_query, text_field)  

    llm = AzureChatOpenAI(
        openai_api_base=OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_ENDPOINT,
        openai_api_version=OPENAI_API_VERSION ,
        deployment_name=OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME,
        openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY,
        openai_api_type = OPENAI_API_TYPE ,
        model_name=OPENAI_MODEL_NAME,
        temperature=0)
    chain = load_qa_chain(llm, chain_type="stuff")

    user_input = get_text()

    if user_input:
        output = query({
            "inputs": {
                "past_user_inputs": st.session_state.past,
                "generated_responses": st.session_state.generated,
                "text": user_input,
            },"parameters": {"repetition_penalty": 1.33}
        },
        chain=chain)
        
        st.session_state.past.append(user_input)
        st.session_state.generated.append(output["generated_text"])
        
    
    if st.session_state['generated']:
        for i in range(len(st.session_state['generated'])-1, -1, -1):
            message(st.session_state["generated"][i], key=str(i))
            message(st.session_state['past'][i], is_user=True, key=str(i) + '_user')
```

But I get this error,

DuplicateWidgetID: There are multiple widgets with the same key='input'.

To fix this, please make sure that the key argument is unique for each widget you create.

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Users\xx\repos\yy\app\pages\02Stuff Search copy.py", line 101, in <module>
    user_input = get_text()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\xx\repos\y\app\pages\02Stuff Search copy.py", line 73, in get_text
    input_text = st.text_input("You: ","", key="input")
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

There is no other code on the script, so I am not sure why it says there are duplicate text boxes.